# getting error of database is locked in python, telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon, py-telegram-bot-api

I am using this code:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import datetime
import pandas as pd

api_id = 11874123
api_hash = '7d78879e63e0b956d5g77575e4665ba3'

chats = ['waqarzaka']

client =  TelegramClient('test', api_id, api_hash)

df = pd.DataFrame()

for chat in chats:
    with TelegramClient('test', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        for message in client.iter_messages(chat, offset_date=datetime.date.today() , reverse=True):
            print(message)
            data = { "group" : chat, "sender" : message.sender_id, "text" : message.text, "date" : message.date}

            temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[1])
            df = df.append(temp_df)

df['date'] = df['date'].dt.tz_localize(None)

df.to_excel("C:\\crypto\\data_{}.xlsx".format(datetime.date.today()), index=False)
```

Result of above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khan/Desktop/hello.py", line 23, in <module>
    with TelegramClient('test', api_id, api_hash) as client:
  File "/home/khan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py", line 294, in __init__
    session.set_dc(
  File "/home/khan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/sessions/sqlite.py", line 168, in set_dc
    self._update_session_table()
  File "/home/khan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/sessions/sqlite.py", line 194, in _update_session_table
    c.execute('delete from sessions')
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you create a second account [to ask this again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74936619/getting-error-while-using-telegram-api-for-data-scraping/74940929#74940929)?

Answer (score 0):

Before creating a new `TelegramClient` instance you have to disconnect the client before using `client.disconnect()`
or remove this line `client = TelegramClient('test', api_id, api_hash)` because there is no need in this case.